# Django: Count only the latest object after grouping by month

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am building a django based app to collect statistics about the users of a certain software.

The goal is to display a chart with the number of users using a version for each month.

Here is the model:

```py
class Installation(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

where `timestamp` is the time when data about the user is collected.

Here is how a sample table looks like:

```
| userid | version | timestamp |
|------------------------------|
|   1    |  3.1    |<sometime> |
|------------------------------|
|   2    |  3.1    |<sometime> |
|------------------------------|
|   1    |  3.2    |<sometime> |
|------------------------------|
|   3    |  3.1    |<sometime> |
```

`<sometime>` represents different timestamps from the same month.
It shows that the `userid = 1` upgraded to version 3.2 within the same month.

Here is my approach:

```py
version_by_month = Installation.objects
                   .annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp'))
                   .values('month', 'version')
                   .annotate(Count('userid', distinct=True))
```

But it has a problem that it will count one user for two versions. For example, it counts `userid = 1` for both versions `3.1` and `3.2` and returns the count for users using `version = 3.1` as 3, which actually should be 2.

For each month I am expecting to have an output in which if a user changes his version then only the version in the latest submission should be counted.

The expected queryset for the table shown above should be something like:

```
[{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'version': 3.1, 'num': 2},
{'month': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'version': 3.2, 'num': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I noticed this is little over a day old, with no answer. While I cannot provide a direct solution as I do not speak Django. But perhaps I can point you in the right direction. 
What you need is to reduce the count universe by first eliminating multiple versions by user. In direct sql this can be accomplished via a sub-select returning only max version per user with the outer select counting the result.

```
-- setup
create table django_count(userid integer, version numeric, dttz timestamp with time zone);
insert into django_count(userid, version, dttz ) 
 values (1, 3.1, now()-interval '1 month')
      , (2, 3.1, now()-interval '1 month' + interval '3 days')
      , (1, 3.2, now()-interval '1 month' + interval '5 days') 
      , (3, 3.1, now()-interval '1 month' + interval '7 days') ;
select * from django_count order by version desc;      

-- count query. This is what you need in raw sql.
select version, count(*)
  from (
        select userid, max(version) as Version, date_trunc('month',dttz) as "For Month"
          from django_count
         group by userid, date_trunc('month',dttz) 
       ) m
 group by version
 order by version;
```

If you can adapt this to Django I'm glad to help, if not I'm sorry I can't help further. Good Luck.